# Can I enumerate users in Well Known Groups?

Tags: c++, security, winapi

(How) can I enumerate programmatically Users in Well Known groups (SidTypeWellKnownGroup) ?
*Ex: "Autenticated Users" or "Domain Users"*

Comment: That's the spirit :). Ok, how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do this in WMI, but I'm not that familiar with it; I prefer using the plain old C APIs anyway.  You can use the [Network Management functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370675.aspx) to do this.  Given the group name, you can use NetGroupGetUsers to get all the members of a group.  To get the group name you can use CreateWellKnownSid (or AllocateAndInitializeSid) and LookupAccountSid.

Comment: NetGroupGetUsers doesn;t work for groups like "Autenticated User" (SidTypeWellKnownGroup). This is a pseudo-group (it exists, but is not listed in Users & Groups). Returns NERR_GroupNotFound

Comment: Pseudo-groups like that are automatically added to the user's token by the system, in this case when the user is authenticated (which I imagine would be present for all users); these are not "real" groups and thus cannot be enumerated.